# Cross referencing between two sub .tex files in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using overleaf. I have two `.tex` files like `table.tex` and `results.tex`. Please note that none of them are `main.tex`. So all my preamble are in `main.tex` file. Now, I would like to refer to a table in my `results.tex` file and the table is written in `table.tex`. I tried to use the xr package but latex won't allow me to have `\usepackage{xr}` line in any other `.tex` files as I need to declare it only in my preamble, i.e. `main.tex` file. So, my question is, is there a way to cross reference between two `.tex` files which are not `main.tex` file?

Comment: Do you include both files in your main document?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, i just write 
`\begin{document}
\input{tables}
\input{results}`

Comment: The referencing should work out of the box with `\ref{...}`. If it does not work for you, please add a [mre] to your question.